# How to import module into xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, import, module, socket.io

I am trying to use `socket.io` in my swift app.

I am new in swift.

I'm following the instructions from https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

but here is the problem, I don't understand how to do the following step.

> (Install Manually) "Copy the Source folder into your Xcode project.
>   (Make sure you add the files to your target(s))"

I don't understand how to achieve this, I have "Added the SocketIO.h and the entire folder into the project, but no matter what, the module is not found.

Am i supposed to add some binaries, if so what are the binaries? What are the extension? How can I identify it?

Here is the image of my xcode project....[image of my screen in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMHln.png)

Comment: have u tried with cocoa pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you clone or or download the socket io project you get a directory with multiple subdirectories. One of the subdirectories is named `Source`. Simply drag that folder into Xcode (into the Project Navigator in the left sidebar).

You will then be presented with a screen like this: 
[image: Xcode - add to target]

Make sure the box for your app is ticked in the "Add to targets" list. This is what the instructions mean by "Make sure you add the files to your target(s)"

Comment: this was actually correct, the thing is to use the Socket Library there are many more things to do. This is a tutorial which i was able to implement socket    http://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/  under  "Adding the Socket.IO Library to the Project" section

Answer (score 0):

If you tried with `cocoa pod` then you have to import this module, else you have to add only two group like this screen shot, Now you can work without importing the module because of all the swift file by default imported into the whole project.

[image: this]

Comment: where is Package.swift? maybe thats the reason why it dosent work