# Cant import module to xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, module

I have the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361827/how-to-import-module-into-xcode): I cant add socket.io module to my project.

I've tried all ways of dragging and dropping as described in answer, I've tried adding files to project from File menu. No matter what I do I get compile error "SocketIO module not found" on string `import SocketIO`

Is there a regular way of adding modules? Command line? Sorry if question sounds dummy - Im new not only to swift but to mac also (bought it to learn swift).

Comment: are you using xcode 9 ? If yes then try https://stackoverflow.com/a/46462200/3548469

Comment: yes, its xCode 9, but adding target manually after drag didnt help eventually, still "no module not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that´s an issue (which it seems to be for not only you) I would go with [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) instead.

Start by:

1. Do this in your terminal: sudo gem install cocoapods
2. Go to your project folder and open the terminal in that folder (cd ...)
3. Do this in your terminal: pod init
4. Remove all content in your newly created pod file and add this instead:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'YourApp' do
    pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 12.0.0' # Or latest version
end
```

5. Do this in your terminal: pod install
6. Open your project, note that you need to open the `.xcworkspace` file to be able to access your pods
7. Import the module `import SocketIO`

I created a sample project for you with CocoaPods installed and I have added SocketIO for you. Remember to run the `.xcworkspace` file. You can download the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ynqyutbtrvttdgm/SocketIOCocaPods.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Did everything as you said, start project from xcworkspace file as said after pod install was complete. Now it says ```Cannot load underlying module for 'SocketIO'``` on ```import SocketIO``` string.

Comment: Same error shows up in test app that you have created, seems like I dont have required dependecies, but which? http://prntscr.com/grhr5d

Comment: OK, managed to solve it. Product->Clean, then Product->Build and now module available. (wonder if everything so complicated on mac :)

Comment: @DenisMatafonov great that it worked out eventually for you. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Add the socketio swift client with CocoaPods , but after that set the source of the client to Swift 3.2 then try to build it. I’m assuming you’re using Xcode 9 . To set the source to swift 3 from Xcode : go to Frameworks, select the SocketIO and go build settings and set Swift version to Swift 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and it killed my 4 hours time.

I did the steps given by @Rashwan L  but it didn't solve my problem though.

- I was set iOS Deployment Target to 10.0 that was my main problem.
- When I changed my iOS Deployment Target to 11.1 it works for me.

Good luck.